# How do I plot multiple, independent cumulative incidence (with competing risk of death) curves on one graph, in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, survival-analysis, survival

I'm using survfit(Surv()) to use the Aalen-Johansen method for calculating cumulative incidence of diagnoses with a competing risk of death.

For each diagnosis column(e.g., Asthma, SlpApnoea, LungInjury ):

- 0 represents a lack of any event through follow-up
- 1 signifies a diagnosis with a particular condition
- 2 signifies death (the occurrence of a competing event that removes the patient from follow-up and further risk of diagnosis).
  Each diagnosis column has a corresponding time column, called DTAsthma, DTSlpApnoea, DTLungInjury  , which shows the number of days until the event in the corresponding column occurred.
  So, I have data frame named Dx_wide structured like this:

| PatientID | Asthma | DTAsthma | SlpApnoea | DTSlpApnoea | LungInjury | DTLungInjury |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 10000 | 1 | 3000 | 1 | 6000 |
| 2 | 2 | 3650 | 2 | 3650 | 2 | 3650 |
| 3 | 1 | 7200 | 0 | 3650 | 0 | 7200 |
| 4 | 0 | 9500 | 0 | 9500 | 0 | 9500 |
| 5 | 2 | 8250 | 1 | 7000 | 0 | 8250 |

So, I run

```
dx1<-survfit(Surv(DTAsthma, Asthma) ~ 1, data=Dx_wide, id=PatientID)
dx2<-survfit(Surv(DTSlpApnoea, SlpApnoea) ~ 1, data=Dx_wide , id=PatientID)
dx3<-survfit(Surv(DTRespiratory, Respiratory) ~ 1, data=Dx_wide, id=PatientID)
```

What I would like to do is then plot the cumulative incidence curves on one graph. Although they're each treated as independent events, they're in the same body system, so it will be interesting to see them together to see how the risk for each diagnosis compares at different ages (follow-up begins at birth). Putting them on top of each other will also clean up the paper, as I'm running similar cumulative incidences for several more groups of diagnoses (e.g., different types of infectious diseases, different types of joint problems). If I have each diagnosis in its own paper, it just ends up being a whole bunch (like 80) of graphs. Which is too difficult for readers digest. Plus, what's interesting is seeing the ones that are similar together.

I am STRUGGLING to figure out how to get this to work, as most functions with cumulative incidence are built around graphing the different competing risks (e.g., showing a curve for death and a curve for asthma). I'm only interested in the curve for each condition (so event==1), but it's still important to calculate it with the competing risk of death considered to avoid overestimating risk (for a good overview, read https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22253319/).

I have tried so many ways of doing this.

```
graphics::matplot
ggsurvfit::ggcuminc
Epi::plotCIF
```

The issue I’m having is that I haven’t found a way to plot multiple curves (that are not strata or events competing with one another) on the same axis. There is a way to combine multiple cumulative incidence curves using survival::ggsurvplot_combine, but I wasn’t able to make that work once I considered competing risk.

I'm not fussy about which method is used. Anything that will get the job done. Even knowing it's possible to do with one of these functions.

One thing I will say, is that I have also tried structuring my data frame longer, so, it looked something like this (named Dx_long):

```
| PatientID | Dx      | Event    | Days     |
| 1         | Asthma  | 0        | 10000    |
| 1         | Apnoea  | 1        | 3000     |
| 1         | Injury  | 1        | 6000     |
| 2         | Asthma  | 2        | 3650     |
| 2         | Apnoea  | 2        | 3650     |
| 2         | Injury  | 2        | 3650     |
```

And then I tried to create survfit objects by typing

```
dx1<-survfit(Surv(Days, Event) ~ 1, data=Dx_long[Dx=="Asthma"], id=PatientID) 
dx2<-survfit(Surv(Days, Event) ~ 1, data=Dx_long[Dx=="Apnoea"], id=PatientID)
dx3<-survfit(Surv(Days, Event) ~ 1, data=Dx_long[Dx=="Injury"], id=PatientID)
```

But I get the error "Error in eval(expr,p) : object 'Dx' not found." I also tried it as

```
dx1<-survfit(Surv(Days, Event) ~ 1, data=Dx_long[Dx_long$Dx=="Asthma"], id=PatientID)
```

But I get the same error. I cannot figure out why. So, if there's something from that which will fix the problem, AMAZING. Particularly if fixing that makes it so I can plot everything on the same graph.

Comment: Before grabbing a package for survival analysis and graphing risk, you first need to learn how to program in R. Code like `DxEvents[Dx=="Asthma"]` is not interpretable. You should first learn how to use R's indexing functions. As the error tells you he interpreter is unable to find an object named "Dx". There is no column named "Dx" in the example. You are expecting the R interpreter to understand that you have several columns that are diagnoses with an acronym of "Dx". That's not yet a feature of R. Perhaps a future version of Githubs Copilot will be able to make such leaps of generalization.

Comment: There is a column named "Dx" in the example  - in the long data frame I showed toward the bottom. I think my example would have been better if I'd given the two different data frame structures different names. I'll go ahead and edit it so the top is called Dx_wide and the bottom is Dx_long. They have different names in my actual data, but I used the name DxEvents as an example name here.

Comment: The Dx_wide example was what I thought was being used. To get a subset from a file named `Dx_long` (which was the name you said it had) for those rows where the `Dx` column values are "Asthma" you would use `Dx_long[Dx_long$Dx=="Asthma", ]` Notice the need to use the file name twice and to unclude a comma. There are many examples in SO showing how to extract a subset from a dataframe using the `subset` function or using data.frame indexing.